# Can I add an "average" line to Highcharts Chart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to recreate a chart (the one below) using [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-basic).  I'm using a basic bar chart, and I'm wondering if there is a way to get a vertical line showing the average of all the bars?  I have the value calculated, I just need it to display as the picture shows.  Can I do this using Highcharts?

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes. You can add it as a plotline, like this:

```
yAxis: {
    // ...Options
    plotLines: [{
        color: 'red',
        value: '15', // Insert your average here
        width: '1',
        zIndex: 4 // To not get stuck below the regular plot lines or series
    }]
}
```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/7ud3bmw5/1/).